# linux dynamic cronjobs

Tags: bash, shell, dynamic

I am looking to keep on adding more ips down the line, and I obviously do not want to keep on adding one by one, can anybody help me build some sort of array dynamically where I can execute a shell file every 10 minutes via the crontab?

Here's what I have in my cronjob:

```
*/10 * * * * scp /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/* 72.119.110.20:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/* 72.119.110.21:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/* 72.119.110.22:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ >/dev/null 2>&1

*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf 72.119.110.20:/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf 72.119.110.21:/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf 72.119.110.22:/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf >/dev/null 2>&1

*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/sip.conf 72.119.110.20:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/sip.conf 72.119.110.21:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
*/10 * * * * scp /etc/asterisk/sip.conf 72.119.110.22:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
```

any kind of help to write out a script to achieve this is greatly appreciated. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ip in 21.119.110.{20,21,22}; do scp ... $ip:...; done
```

Should work.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. What if I have different classes ip that doesn't always start the same?

Comment: then use normal for loop. `for ip in 10.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in bash:

```
IPADDRESSES=( 10.0.0.1 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 )

for IPADDRESS in ${IPADDRESSES[@]}; do
  echo ${IPADDRESS}
done
```